# Spring OAuth2 redirect to original URL on successful auth

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm able to successfully complete the OAuth auth, however am struggling with working how to then send the request back to the original requested URL. An example scenario is as follows:

Incoming request to: `/some-protected-resource`

As the user is not authorised yet we complete the OAuth flow.

As per the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` docs the user is redirected back to webapp root when I don't have a `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` specified however I would like to redirect them back to whatever URL they originally requested.

I've tried specifying the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` however it doesn't seem like the OAuth requests go through the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is exactly what you want to achieve, so it might be that you customized the authorization process so it redirects you to the root.
Provide more details on your configuration.